# Calling external script in .sql file with decisioning logic

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLplus decode to execute scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345621/sqlplus-decode-to-execute-scripts)

I've looked all over and can't seem to find the answer to my question, but I'm relatively new to oracle, but well versed in database/SQL, so it may be a misunderstanding on my part. I am using Oracle .SQL files using a mix of PL/SQL and SQL*Plus in Linux (ubuntu) to fill out basic tables within a database, and I have a number of scripts that are being called from one "master script".

So for example, I have a master script that's like:

```
@folder1/script1.sql
@folder2/script2.sql
```

Within each of the scripts, i have SQL statements calling out to a package within my database to populate some fields. What I want to be able to do is prompt the user for input to determine the environment, and then run certain scripts based on that input. I know how to take a variable in within my script, but when i do that, i don't seem to be able to call external scripts.

So for example, I know how to take a variable in like this:

```
set define on
def &&env=env1

begin

        if '&&env' = 'env1' then
        .
        . 
        .
        .
        END IF;
END;
```

Which will prompt the user for the variable exactly how I want it to, but I don't seem to be able to call external scripts within this block like mentioned above. To the best of my understanding, this is because within the Begin/End block it is executing PL/SQL and outside of that is SQL*Plus (i could be wrong about that, again relatively new to oracle)

Searching online, i've found people recommending using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE within the script to call an external script, though this is considered bad practice, but I can seem to get that to work. I assume this is because the script needs to be on the server since PL/SQL is server side (won't work in my case).

At the end of the day, what I want is something that functions to this effect, but doing this doesn't seem to work.

```
set define on
def &&env=env1

begin

        if '&&env' = 'env1' then
               @folder1\script1.sql
               @folder1\script2.sql
        ELSEIF '&&env' = 'env2'
               @folder2\script1.sql
               @folder2\script2.sql
        END IF;
END;
```

However, the above code does not work, it fails when trying to call the external script, and i can't seem to find anything in my search online to figure out if this is possible or not.